# Statistical Mode of an array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mode

I need to find Statistical mode of an array. Consider

> val data = Array(101, 100, 101, 100, 100, 100, 103, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 150, 150, 150, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150)

[Above 'data' array is sample one.] Actually array contains 200 values for which  I need to find Statistical mode value (common most occurred value) for every consecutive 10 data points using Scala.

Any idea that would work is appreciated.

Comment: So, what was the problem with the code you wrote to solve this?

Comment: I was able to extract only the size of most occurred value for each consecutive 10 data points.
data.grouped(10).map(_.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)).toArray

Comment: Your idea works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.grouped(10).map(_.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1).toList`